# Replace class in order to replace image on click with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I read a number of articles and answers here on Stack Overflow but none of them answered my question as I'm really a noob when it comes to jQuery and I'm not sure how to do this.

I have a HTML landing page on which I'm trying to show several images on which you click and they get replaced with another image and when clicked again or at another image the original one is shown.

I have this so far:

```
<div class="santa">
  <img class="show" src="images/santa.png" alt="">
  <img class="hide" src="images/bubble.png" alt="">
</div>
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
.show { display: block; }
```

I want to show `santa.png` by default and when clicked on to change it to `bubble.png`, meaning default class is `show` and when clicked on it's `hide` for santa and vice versa.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple way to do this is to call `toggle()` on both the displayed and hidden images when one is clicked. This will invert the display state of both elements simultaneously:

```js
$('.hide, .show').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('div').find('.hide, .show').toggle();
})
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
.show { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="santa">
  <img class="show" src="images/santa.png" alt="Santa">
  <img class="hide" src="images/bubble.png" alt="Bubble">
</div>
<div class="santa">
  <img class="show" src="images/santa.png" alt="Santa2">
  <img class="hide" src="images/bubble.png" alt="Bubble2">
</div>
```

If you actually want to change the `class` values on the elements, then you can use `toggleClass()` instead:

```js
$('.hide, .show').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('div').find('.hide, .show').toggleClass('hide show');
})
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
.show { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="santa">
  <img class="show" src="images/santa.png" alt="Santa">
  <img class="hide" src="images/bubble.png" alt="Bubble">
</div>
<div class="santa">
  <img class="show" src="images/santa.png" alt="Santa2">
  <img class="hide" src="images/bubble.png" alt="Bubble2">
</div>
```

Comment: I was just about to post an answer suggesting the `.toggleClass()` method as an alternative, but you have that one covered as well. Anyway, I don't think you can get any more efficient than the first solution.

Comment: @rory-mccrossan This worked for me, the only problem I'm now facing is that I have 5 divs and each has 2 images (hide and show) and once one of the images in one of the 5 is clicked all of the images on the page are being changed. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: In that case you need to get the nearest parent `div` and `find` the `.hide`/`.show` within that. I updated the answer for you to show you how to do this

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Since u are a beginner, my humble request is to learn vanillajs thoroughly before using libraries like jquery.

here is a pure js approach.. Cheers

```js
let santaimg = document.getElementById('santa');
let bubbleimg = document.getElementById('bubble');

santaimg.onclick = showBubbleHideSanta;

function showBubbleHideSanta() { 
 santaimg.classList += " hide";
 //santaimg.classList -= "show";
 bubbleimg.classList -= " hide";
 //bubbleimg.classList += "show";
}
```

```css
.show {
  display:block;
}
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/49/Jonathan_G_Meath_portrays_Santa_Claus.jpg/220px-Jonathan_G_Meath_portrays_Santa_Claus.jpg" id="santa" class="show"/>
<img src = "https://sophosnews.files.wordpress.com/2017/05/shutterstock_296886146.jpg?w=780&h=408&crop=1" id="bubble" class="hide"/>
```

Comment: This only appears to work once. It doesn't toggle. I'd suggest using `classList.toggle()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 0):

Try this...if you have two images only...

HTML

```
<div class="santa">
                <img class="show" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="img">
                <img class="hide" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="img">
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.show{
    display:block;
 }
 .hide{
    display:none;
 }
 img{
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    cursor:pointer;
 }
```

JS

```
 jQuery('.show, .hide').click(function() {
      jQuery('.show, .hide').toggle();
    });
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show/hide an element I suggest you to use .hide() and .show() 
It's pure JQuery and no need of CSS.

> "The matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "none" ), except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value"
>   http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Here is an exemple:

HTML

```
<div>
    <img class="santa_img" src="images/santa.png" alt="santa">
    <img class="bubble_img" src="images/bubble.png" alt="bubble">
</div>
```

JS (JQuery)

```
$(".santa_img").click(function(){

    $(".santa_img").hide();
    $(".bubble_img").show();

})

$(".bubble_img").click(function(){

    $(".bubble_img").hide();
    $(".santa_img").show();

})

$(".bubble_img").hide(); //Hidden by default
```